# NSURLConnectionDataTask not getting any response

Tags: nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondatatask

I have a `NSURLConnectionDataTask` created by the shared `NSURLSession` via `dataTaskWithRequest`. I `resume()` it, but the completion handler never gets called. Observations:

- Sending the same request using `NSURLConnection`’s `sendSynchronousRequest` works fine.
- Trying a plain GET URL for the data task works fine with the same code.
- When I log the state of the data task, I see that bytes are sent, but no bytes are ever received. Both `error` and `response` are `nil`. The state of the task is `running`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to set the HTTP method to `POST`. A `GET` request with non-empty body apparently stalls like that.